# Output without overwriting

Tags: java, io, overwrite

Is it possible to write text to a file without overwriting previous data?

What I have done always is:

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
BufferedReader in;
PrintWriter out;

try{
    in = new BufferedReader( new FileReader("somefile.txt"));
    out = new PrintWriter( new FileWriter("somefile.txt"));

    String input = "";
    while(input != null){
        sb.append(input + "\n");
        input = in.readLine();
    }
    in.close()

    out.print(sb.toString());

    // now start doing what I want.
```

Is this the correct way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the append mode for `FileWriter` to avoid overwriting existing data:

```
new PrintWriter( new FileWriter("somefile.txt", true));
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [FileWriter API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html). There's a constructor that accepts a boolean parameter --  you may wish to use it.